# p:commandButton not working inside c:forEach

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

i am trying to use `p:commandButton` inside  `c:forEach` tag but this commandButton not invoked:

```
    <c:forEach items="#{carnetOrdreBean.selectedOrdreList}" var="ordre">

      <p:commandButton action="#{carnetOrdreBean.annulerOrdreChoisi}" value="Annuler" rendered="#{ordre.voirAnnulerOuNon}">
           <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{ordre}" target="#{carnetOrdreBean.selectedOrdre}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
   </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Have u try change the p:commandButton action from `action` to `actionListener`?

Comment: or change `c:forEach` to `ui:repeat` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as he said Andry in the comment, the solution is change `c:forEach`  to `ui:repeat`

Comment: 1 think I want to add here is , in both c:forEach and ui:repeat h:commandButton and h:commandLink actions will not get invoked